# Complexity of strncmp in string.h

Tags: c, string, time-complexity, strncmp

I would like to know the time complexity of `int strncmp(const char *__s1, const char *__s2, size_t __n)` which is in the C library(`string.h)`.

I have to study the complexity of my whole program which is calling strncmp thousands of time, I can't ignore this complexity.
Where can I find documentation about the complexity of c library function ?

Comment: Your can derive the answer yourself considering the linear operation of comparing one char after each other.

Comment: Time complexity of strcmp in character comparisons is `O(k)` where `k` is the length of the common prefix up to n, and  `k <= max[n, l1, l2]` strictly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard imposes no requirements on the complexity. That is entirely up to the implementation. But there's absolutely no reason to expect it to be anything else than `O(__n)`

- It's trivial to write an implementation that satisfies `O(__n)`, so there's no reason to suspect that a real implementation made by professionals is worse.
- It's impossible to write an implementation that is better than `O(__n)`, so that will not happen.

But if you want to be sure, you have to study the particular implementation you're using.